# Is it possible to optimize this dynamic programming code?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization

This code is taking more than half an hour for a data set of 200000 floats.

```
import numpy as np
try:
    import progressbar
    pbar = progressbar.ProgressBar(widgets=[progressbar.Percentage(),
        progressbar.Counter('%5d'), progressbar.Bar(), progressbar.ETA()]) 
except:
    pbar = list

block_length = np.loadtxt('bb.txt.gz') # get data file from http://filebin.ca/29LbYfKnsKqJ/bb.txt.gz (2MB, 200000 float numbers)
N = len(block_length) - 1

# arrays to store the best configuration
best = np.zeros(N, dtype=float)
last = np.zeros(N, dtype=int)
log = np.log

# Start with first data cell; add one cell at each iteration
for R in pbar(range(N)):
    # Compute fit_vec : fitness of putative last block (end at R)
    #fit_vec = fitfunc.fitness(
    T_k = block_length[:R + 1] - block_length[R + 1]
    #N_k = np.cumsum(x[:R + 1][::-1])[::-1]
    N_k = np.arange(R + 1, 0, -1)
    fit_vec = N_k * (log(N_k) - log(T_k))

    prior = 4 - log(73.53 * 0.05 * ((R+1) ** -0.478))
    A_R = fit_vec - prior #fitfunc.prior(R + 1, N)

    A_R[1:] += best[:R]

    i_max = np.argmax(A_R)
    last[R] = i_max
    best[R] = A_R[i_max]

# Now find changepoints by iteratively peeling off the last block
change_points = np.zeros(N, dtype=int)
i_cp = N
ind = N
while True:
    i_cp -= 1
    change_points[i_cp] = ind
    if ind == 0:
        break
    ind = last[ind - 1]
    change_points = change_points[i_cp:]

print edges[change_points] # show result
```

The first loop is very slow because the length of arrays is R at every iteration, i.e. increasing, leading to N^2 complexity.

Is there any way to optimize this code further, e.g. through pre-computation? I am also happy with solutions using other programming languages.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/97539/9357)

Comment: This hasn't gotten much attention because it lacked a key tag, `numpy`.  There aren't as many `numpy` knowledgeable posters on CR.  Plus CR is pickier about question format.  But i agree with the CR comments that this question needs more explanation.  It should also have a small test data set.  The `progressbar` is an unnecessary complication.

Comment: I tried running your code.  I had to guess at `block_length`, got invalid errors for the logs, lots of `0` in `last`, and index errors in the `change_points` loop.  Until you gives us code that is cut-n-paste runnable, you aren't going to get much help.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate `A_R` (up to the `fit-prior` step) as a upper triangular NxN matrix with:

```
def trilog(n):
    nn = n[:-1,None]-n[None,1:]
    nn[np.tril_indices_from(nn,-1)]=1
    return nn

T_k = trilog(block_length)
N_k = trilog(-np.arange(N+1))
fit_vec = N_k * (np.log(N_k) - np.log(T_k))
R = np.arange(N)+1
prior = 4 - log(73.53 * 0.05 * (R ** -0.478))
A_R = fit_vec - prior
A_R = np.triu(A_R,0)
print(A_R)
```

I haven't worked through the logic of calculation and applying `best`.

I've only done this with small arrays.  For your full problem, the corresponding matrix is too large for my memory.

```
B=np.ones((200000,200000),float)
```

So just from memory considerations you might be stuck with the `for R in range(N)` iteration.